# XML Import how would you do it?

Tags: xml, vb.net, sql-server-2005

XML is used as one of our main integration points.  it comes over by many clients at a time but too many clients importing at the same time can slow down our database to a crawl.
Someone has to have solved a problem like this.

I am basically using VB to parse through the data and import what i want and don't want.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you wanting to store XML in a SQL Server 2005 database in the XML data type?  Or shred the contents of XML for inserting into a database table?

Comment: Shred the contents importing to multiple tables from 1 xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered creating a [SSIS package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services)?  You can efficiently import data from many different source types this way.

Here's a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188032(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: does an SSIS Package work for a multiple Client Scenario.
There could be 100 different locations for the xml files...

Comment: If the files have the same schema and they are on an accesible drive, it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without specifics it's hard to say where your slow spot is. Are you measuring where the time is being spent in your application?

I find that many times, a large data set is being materialized unnecessarily, which eats memory and can kill performance. This could happen in your scenario if you receive the XML input data and store it in an `XmlDocument` before you start parsing through the data. This will kill you if the `XmlDocument` is large.

If possible, aim to process the data incrementally by reading it with an `XmlReader`. Some datasets are amenable to this approach: the processing required doesn't need a lot of context, but proceeds linearly across the data. In this case you'll see a huge improvement over sucking everything down into an `XmlDocument`. However, other datasets are so structured that you really do have to have everything in core before continuing.

Again, it's hard to say if there is a better way without understanding how the input data is structured.